# How to send fixed voltage Android audio jack

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, audiotrack

I have a small device that operates using the smartphones audio jack. I would like to send a fixed amount of voltage in the audio jack in order for the device to operate. I am using the AudioTrack in the MODE_STREAM. I also have a buffer in which I write a sine signal of fixed frequency as found in [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=228).

It sends single tones to the audio jack. Does it mean that the output voltage is fixed or it varies according to the sine signal? Is there a way to ensure that the output voltage of the audio jack is at a fixed value?

Thanks!

Comment: For a given volume setting on a given device, the AC output voltage may well be steady.  But you should expect it to vary between devices and by volume settings (and even related ones such as audio equalization) on a given device.  It sounds like you need to limit your expectations, and to start by thinking about the difference between AC vs. DC as a means of transferring power.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question it seems that the AC output voltage is controlled by the sound volume level and it seems to be device dependent. Thanks for the comment!